# Add a active link to custom ul in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a custom list(ul) in wordpress sidebar. I want to add active class to list items.

```
<ul  class="sidebar-list">
 <li> <a href="index.php/owle/">OWLE</a></li>
 <li><a href="index.php/sink-or-swim/">Sink or Swim</a></li>
 <li><a href="index.php/swim-and-survive/">Swim and Survive</a></li>
 <li><a href="index.php/vwsc/">VWSC</a></li>
 <li><a href="index.php/water-smart/">Water Smart</a></li>
 <li><a href="index.php/grey-medallion/">Grey Medallion</a></li>
 <li><a href="index.php/aquatic-pd-workshops/">Aquatic PD Workshops</a></li>

 <li><a href="index.php/edu-from-anywhere/">Edu From Anywhere</a></li>
 <li><a href="index.php/bronze-e-lifesaving/">Bronze e-Lifesaving</a></li>
 <li><a href="index.php/water-smart-award/">Water Smart Award</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.php/victorian-water-safety-certificate/">Victorian Water Safety Certificate</a></li>
 <li><a href="index.php/edu-from-anywhere-newsletter/">Edu From Anywhere Newsletter</a></li>
 <li><a href="index.php/edu-casual-instructor/">Edu Casual Instructor</a></li>

 <li><a href="index.php/grey-medallion/">Grey Medallion</a></li>
 <li><a href="index.php/sink-or-swim/">Sink or Swim</a></li>
 <li><a href="index.php/edu-instructor-of-year-profile/">Edu Instructor of year Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.php/swim-survive-licensee-of-year/">Swim & Survive Licensee of year</a></li>
   </ul>


<li class="active"> <a href="index.php/owle/">OWLE</a></li>
```

should look like on 'index.php/owle/'.

Comment: Add `active` class to all list items?

Comment: no add active class to list item on current page. like   <li class="active"> <a href="index.php/owle/">OWLE</a></li> when user is on 'index.php/owle/'.  just like current-menu-item on wordpress main navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your wordpress them's custom javascript. Lot of themes have that. Check theme customization.

```
 var url = window.location;
 // Will only work if string in href matches with location
 $('sidebar-list li a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');

 // Will also work for relative and absolute hrefs
  $('sidebar-list li a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
 }).parent().addClass('active');
```

if your theme don't have this you have to hardcode this. I recommend you add this to your footer.php

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
 if( in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
         $classes[] = 'active ';  // your new class
 }
 return $classes;
```

}

> Try this code, It Works. All you have to do is juss change those class names with the classes you are using.

Answer (score 0):

you no need to do coding for it.

create sidebar with wordpress menu.

wordpress menu have default class for currunt item

> current-menu-item

and you can add css to it ..